# Is there a safe way detecting if a date is yesterday?

Tags: javascript

I want to detect if a date was yesterday. I only have a UTC date string available for that which I format specified on the user navigator language:

```js
let dateStr = "2020-04-07 15:36:55";
let utcDate = new Date(`${ dateStr }Z`.replace(" ", 'T'));
let formattedUtcDate = new Date(utcDate).toLocaleDateString(navigator.language, {
  day: "2-digit",
  month: "2-digit",
  year: "numeric"
});
let currentDate = new Date().toLocaleDateString(navigator.language, {
  day: "2-digit",
  month: "2-digit",
  year: "numeric"
});

if (formattedUtcDate === currentDate) {
  console.log("Today");
} else if (true) { //????????
  console.log("Yesterday");
}
```

Any idea? I can't use the timestamp solution here that I've found on SO. So there must be another way handling this.

Comment: You got this far `formattedUtcDate === currentDate`, now do the same thing but with yesterdays date instead of the currentDate.

Comment: Well, thats an idea. I'll try that out.

Comment: See also https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+date+object+add+day+site:stackoverflow.com for how to subtract a day from a date instance.

Comment: Also if you have the option I highly recommend using [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/) over the built in Date type. It is much richer in functionality.

Comment: @Igor Nice lib. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 0):

You are very close to the solution ...

just remember that `new Date()` [constructor can have parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), as year, month, day, hour, minute and second, like:

```js
new Date(2020, 3, 7, 0, 0, 0) // month is 0 based! 3 = April
```

and adding 0, 0, 0 to represent time, will give it the beginning of the day of the given date, with this new information, to calculate the start of the day every day:

```js
var now = new Date()
var startOfDay = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate(), 0, 0, 0)
```

to get UTC values, use the UTC getters:

- `getUTCFullYear()`
- `getUTCMonth()`
- `getUTCDate()`

same as if you want to find the `endOfDay` (use `23, 59, 59)` and the time) and then you can compare the `.getTime()` to actually compare if the given day is:

```js
if (utcDate.getTime() < startOfDay.getTime()) ... // past
else if (utcDate.getTime() > endOfDay.getTime()) ... // future
else ... // today
```

in the code above you can omit `.getTime()` as Javascript will infer such operation

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do it by creating a date object for yesterday as well. To do it, subtract `86400000` milliseconds (a day, `24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 = 86400000`) from the current time (represented by `Date.now()`):

```js
let dateStr = "2020-04-06 15:36:55";
let utcDate = new Date(`${ dateStr }Z`.replace(" ", 'T'));
let formattedUtcDate = new Date(utcDate).toLocaleDateString(navigator.language, {
  day: "2-digit",
  month: "2-digit",
  year: "numeric"
});
let currentDate = new Date().toLocaleDateString(navigator.language, {
  day: "2-digit",
  month: "2-digit",
  year: "numeric"
});
let yesterdayDate = new Date(Date.now() - 86400000).toLocaleDateString(navigator.language, {
  day: "2-digit",
  month: "2-digit",
  year: "numeric"
});

if (formattedUtcDate === currentDate) {
  console.log("Today");
} else if (formattedUtcDate === yesterdayDate) {
  console.log("Yesterday");
}
```